# Popen.stdin with multithreading problem, does not work

Tags: python, multithreading, stdin

I am trying to run a shell from my python program.
I have used a mltithreaded approach where an input from user is accepted and should be executed via the shell.

Everything seems right, except that the program execution just doesn't take place beyond stdin.

I am not sure if there is something wrong with the way I have used Popen.stdin.

So please help on what is wrong here.

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
import shlex
import threading
from Queue import Queue


class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,func,args):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.func=func
        self.args=args

    def run(self):
        apply(self.func,self.args)



def bash(command,output):
    commandList=shlex.split('python test.py')   
    process=Popen(commandList,stdout=PIPE,stdin=PIPE,stderr=PIPE,shell=True)
    print process.stdout.readlines()
    while (process.pole()==None):
        #commandList=shlex.split(command.get(1))
        print 'bash'
        process.stdin.write(command.get(1))
        process.stdin.flush()
        output.put(process.stdout.readlines(),1)
        process.stdout.flush()



def communicate(command,output):
    while True:
        command.put(raw_input('enter command>'))
        print 'communicate'
        print output.get(1)



funcs=[bash,communicate]
nfuncs=len(funcs)    

def main():

    command=Queue(1)
    output=Queue(1)
    threads=[]

    for i in range(nfuncs):
        t=MyThread(funcs[i],(command,output))
        threads.append(t)

    for i in range(nfuncs):
        threads[i].start()

    for i in range(nfuncs):
        threads[i].join()

    print 'successful'       

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

I have given the output below.

```
karthik@ubuntu:~/TerminalChatBot/test$ python threadTerminal.py
enter command>ls
communicate
```

After this there is no execution. I can't even use ctrl+c to stop the python script. It just hangs.

NOTE: the thread communicate needs to be there as we need to integrate this code with the bigger module.

Comment: From the look of it, I would suggest you use [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) instead of `subprocess` + `threading`

Comment: Why don't you use python multiprocessing approach instead of multithreading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minor things:

It's `process.poll()` not `process.pole()`.

Instead of

```
 for i in range(nfuncs):
    t=MyThread(funcs[i],(command,output))
    threads.append(t)
```

do

```
 for func in nfuncs:
    t=MyThread(func,(command,output))
    threads.append(t)
```

Now, why are you running `python test.py`? Don't you want to run `ls communicate` in a shell, in which case you should be doing something like:

```
def bash(command,output):
    process=Popen('bash',stdout=PIPE,stdin=PIPE,stderr=PIPE,shell=True)
    print process.stdout.readlines()
    # I don't really understand what's going on here
    while (process.pole()==None):
        print 'bash'
        process.stdin.write(command.get(1))
        process.stdin.flush()
        output.put(process.stdout.readlines(),1)
        process.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: python test.py was for testing purpose only. And thanks for highlighting about poll(). I have made the changes you have suggested, but still, the same problem exists. It asks for a command, I enter it, it prints communicate and that's it. It just stops. What may be cause of this?

Comment: Have looked at using Popen.communicate() instead of writing to and reading from stdin and stdout? Those are known to deadlock in some circumstances.

Comment: Also, if that doesn't work, you'd be better off debugging the code without the threading just for simplicity, as it's not clear to me it would work even then.

Answer (score 0):

could it be that it keeps hanging on `process.stdout.readlines()`? Perhaps no line ending can be found. Try stdout.read(1) to read one character and see what happens.

Comment: Why would line endings effect `readlines()` ending or not? It may split at line endings, but it reads to end of file.

Comment: I had a similar problem using readline() on a pyserial input. Without a line ending, pyserial kept waiting; no way to know when the 'file'ends. Pyserial is completely different from a shell, I get it, but who knows...

Comment: So the problem was there was no __file ending__, not no line ending, right? `read()` with no limit would have hung too?

Comment: It would read until end of file or  until end of line. So if both were absence, it hang. `read()` hang without the file ending being defined as an occuring character at the end of the feed.

Comment: You are right though: readlines() probably would have needed an occuring file ending character defined as well. Anyway we are spending more time discussing than it would cost to give it a try to read one character...